# LUIS Two Geographies in a expression

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I Defined an intent in luis. It is meant to find departure and arrivals in a string.

I want both to be predefined geogrpahies. But I can only mark one as geography.  If I mark two as geographie it tells me that an entitiy is already a geography. 
Also I cant create two prebuild types of geography

here the intent definition 
[image]

and here the entities

[image]

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's a limitation in LUIS, you can't use the same entity for 2 parameters.

If you are willing to use your own customized *location entity extractor*, I suggest using **Hierarchical Entities** as explained [here](https://www.luis.ai/Help/#CreatingApplication) Hierarchical Entities section.

You will create a parent entity (let's call it Location), then add 2 children to it (TO, FROM).

Now you will be able to use the children in the parameter you are trying to fill in the window attached.